# Parquet metadata files useful on HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, parquet

We use Spark to generate parquet files on HDFS.

Spark generate 4 files, the parquet with data, and 3 meta-data files. The thing is, the 3 meta-data files take 1 block, here 128M, as we run many tasks like this, this could take lot of space for nothing.

Are there files needed? Or is it a good way to deal with?

Comment: Without the metadata it's pretty hard to make sense of the Parquet files.

Comment: We use Hive as data warehouse, query with PrestoDB and Hive

Comment: _"meta-data files take 1 block, here 128M ... could take lot of space"_ >> **no.** The HDFS block size has no significant impact on _physical_ disk usage. It's all about _logical_ distribution of data, for large files. When a client writes into an HDFS file, when the current block reaches 128 MB, then a new block will be created (and replicated on random nodes); but in the end, each block will be stored as a regular Linux file, byte for byte (plus some metadata in an extra Linux file).

Comment: D'oh, I was not sure about this, thanks you to clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metadata file in the parquet output folder is optional and it is not needed by spark to read in parquet files as each parquet file has metadata embedded in it.

On the other hand, it's needed by `thrift` to read those files.

In Spark 2.0, writing Parquet summary files by default. [Ref. [SPARK-15719](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15719).]

Comment: Nice thanks you, so I can safely remove it. Do you know if it's possible to set ``ENABLE_JOB_SUMMARY`` to false with Spark 1.6.2?

Comment: I'm not sure such a conf exists in parquet before spark 2.